# Disabling screen blanking in GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, gnome3, acpi, screen-energy-saving

We are using a Debian 7 machine with the default GNOME 3 installation to display content on an information display. This display needs to remain on until the connected computer is switched off. However, GNOME 3 switches the display off after a few minutes.

I can't seem to find a way to control this behaviour in either the system settings tools nor using dconf-editor. There is a [prominent Google hit](http://blog.tordeu.com/?p=292) suggesting to change the

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-ac
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-display-battery
org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay
```

keys, but this did not change anything.

So, how does one control and disable screen blanking in GNOME 3?

Answer (score 5):

Try disabling DPMS and Screen saver:

```
xset -dpms
xset s off
```

Comment: Use `xset +dpms; xset s on` to restore the original state.